# Why do Chrome, Firefox and IE all render fixed-width SELECT controls differently?

Tags: html, cross-browser

I am **losing hair** on this one ... it seems that when I fix width an HTML SELECT control it renders its width differently depending on the browser.

Any idea how to to standardize this without having to turn to multiple style sheets?

Here is what I am working with:

```
.combo
{
    padding: 2px;
    width: 200px;
}

.text
{
    padding: 2px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

This is my document type for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form controls will always be less obedient to styling attempts,in particular selects and file inputs, so the only way to reliably style them cross-browser and with future-proofing in mind, is to replace them with JavaScript or Flash and mimic their functionality

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `font-size` on the selects as well, that can affect how they are rendered. Also consider the `min-width` and `max-width` properties.

Comment: The OP wants a fixed width though and not a variable width. I ++'d u because of the font-size but the *-width doesn't make sense.

Comment: Don't really remember about 2008, but this days the max-width did fix the problem for "select". +'d this!

Answer (score 2):

input[type=text],
select {
     border: solid 1px #c2c1c1;
     width: 150px;
     padding: 2px;
     }

// then

select {
     width: 156px; //needs to be input[type=text] width + (border and padding)
     }

/*
The input[type=text] width = width + padding + border

The select width just equals width.  The padding and border get rendered inside that width constraint.  That's just the way SELECT rolls...

*/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you remove all default margins and padding, and define them explicitly. Make sure you're using a proper DOCTYPE and therefore rendering IE in Standards Mode.

Comment: I included my DOCTYPE in my original question ... does this look correct?

Answer (score 1):

You may use faked dropdown widget and replace the SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers tend to limit the amount you can style form controls with CSS, because form controls have a lot of complicated styling that varies between operating systems. CSS can’t describe that fully, so browsers put some of it off limits.

Eric Meyer wrote a good article on the subject:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/15/formal-weirdness/

The best you can do is accept you don’t have complete control over the look of form fields, and experiment with whatever styling is really important.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) or Chrome's "Inspect Element" feature (right click on the select control, click "inspect element") to see exactly what style properties are being inherited/rendered for that specific object. That should lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all these suggestions ... and I finally have it so it looks good in IE and Firefox.  Looks like there is something wrong with the padding on the SELECT control.  If I increase the width of the SELECT by 2 pixels the now size correctly.

```
 .combo
 {
     padding: 2px;
     width: 206px;
 }

.text
{
    padding: 2px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

However, Chrome still does not show them the same size.

Comment: What @Radu said: form controls limit your styling options. Find a Javascript < select > replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Martinator is correct.

Sounds like you're trying to control the width of various types of inputs or menus across bowsers. You can directly select the object and specify the width. For example:

```
select {
  width:350px;
}
```

Or you can do this with text area:

```
select {
      width:350px;
}
```

Other types of inputs require the syntax Martinator mentions. So, for a text, input, or even file type input, you'd do this for each one:

```
input[type=text] {
      width:350px;
}

input[type=input] {
      width:350px;
}

input[type=file] {
      width:350px;
}
```